# How to download kde or gnome from synaptic for offline installation

Tags: 12.04, gnome, synaptic, offline, kde4

I know how to install **GNOME 3** and **KDE** using `apt-get`.

But i want to know how to, only download, from synaptic package manager, these shells. When i search for `kubuntu-desktop` in synaptic then the download file shows nearly 4MB but i clearly remember the actual size was near >100 mb. Just for information both are already installed in my laptop.

So the question is - 
How to download the actuall >100 mb **KUbuNTU-DESKTOP** so that i can just, without any hesitation install it in offline computer which is using ubuntu 12.04.

Same for the GNOME 3. Please help me out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a package without installing using apt-get:

`apt-get --download-only install <packagename>`

To (re)download all currently installed packages do:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs apt-get --download-only --reinstall -y install
```

The .deb files will be stored under `/var/cache/apt/archives`. Take those files and copy them to the offline machine. Then you can install them without downloading.

This assumes that at least the package list of the currently available packages are in sync on both systems. If not, things will get more complicated...

Comment: **apt-get -d install gnome-shell** is not downloading anything. and the next command, its for some reason ends its execution.

Comment: And please also tell me what to download in order to fully download the kubuntu-desktop please.

Comment: If it's not downloading anything then the needed files are probably already in '/var/cache/apt/archives' from a previous install. If gnome-shell is already installed you need to add the --reinstall switch.

Comment: `apt-cache depends <package_name>` lists the package dependencies

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i ran JANITOR in ubuntu-tweak to clean. I double checked the folder u meantioned there is nothing in there except a LOCK and PARTIAL. But still the command is not downloading why? and another thing i installed gnome3 from ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3.

Comment: wow. the dependencies and recommendations are listed now how to download them altogether please help !

Comment: Janitor from ubuntu-tweak? Sure this tool cleaned your "unnecessary" caches... I've absolutely no idea what else it did to "optimize" your system, so I'm out. If I were you I would try to understand the long commandline from my answer and find out which part is failing. Good luck!

Comment: Thats sounds like i am doomed.